# Change value of a variable in a factory AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Using a factory in AngularJS is it possible to change the TokenRestangular URL value.

for example could I do this:

```
 .factory('projectFactory', ['TokenRestangular', function (TokenRestangular) {
        var factory = {
            projects: []
        };

        factory.get = function () {
            return
             resource = TokenRestangular.all('project');
               resource.getList()
                .then(function (project) {
                    factory.project = project;
                    return factory.project;

                })
        };
        return factory;
    }]);
```

and in my controller change the value of resource i.e.

```
   var projects = projectFactory.get()
   projects.TokenRestangular.all('a_different_url');
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a service but not with a factory. A service is created as a singleton so each time you inject it you will get the same instance. With a factory you will get a new one.

You should be able to have a simple service like the following and inject it into your controller:

```
myApp.service('SimpleService', function() {
    this.localValue = 0;
    this.setLocalValue = function(newValue) {
      this.localValue = newValue;
    }
});
```

Un-tested but should give you enough to go on!

Comment: > It's possible with a service but not with a factory. --- do you mean the other way around?

Comment: @Spike - Nope, I meant it how I said :)